# How to print a matrix using goto statement

Tags: c++

How to print a matrix using only goto statement?

I tried but my code is not working .

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   //int i=0,j=0;
   int arr[3][3] = { (1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9) };

   printf("The matrix is");

   int i = 0;
   printrow:
   {
      int j = 0;
      printcolumn:
      {
         int j = 0;
         if (j < 3)
         {
            printf("%d", arr[i][j]);
            j++;
            goto printcolumn;
         }
         if (i < 2)
         {
            printf("/n");
            i++;
            goto printrow;
         }
      }
   }   

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you have to use `goto`? Is this some sort of made up coding challenge? A normal coder would use a proper loop construct such as `for` or `while`.

Comment: Yes only goto and its an assignment.

Comment: Close to a typo: the `int j=0;` line **after** `printcolumn` resets the column index on each iteration (infinite loop). But unless as an exercise about goto this is a very uncommon requirement: nested loops are much more readable...

Comment: Hope it is just an example of what should never end in production code and why...

Comment: Use consistent indentation.  That will make the problems more apparent.

Comment: The instructor who gave you this assignment should be fired.  (Or, perhaps, celebrated for the invention of the time machine that brought him here from 1968.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   //int i=0,j=0;
   int arr[3][3] = { {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9} };

   printf("The matrix is\n");

   int i = 0;

   printrow:
   {
      int j = 0;
      printcolumn:
      {
         if (j < 3)
         {
            printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);
            j++;
            goto printcolumn;
         }
      }
      if (i < 2)
     {
        printf("\n");
        i++;
        goto printrow;
     }
   }   

   return 0;
}
```

> { (1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9) }

PS: Watch what you're doing. Is that the way you declare a matrix?

Answer (score 1):

You have an additional statement `int j = 0;` after `printcolumn:`, which resets `j` each loop. It also shadows the former definition of `j`.

Remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You have small mistake there, you are clearing `j` to zero twice, remove the second one.

Also newline escape sequence is normal slash instead of the back one...